# PHP syntax error, unexpected '[' in using an array

Tags: php

I am using this code below :

```
$data = array();
$value = reset($value);
$data[0] = (string) $value->attributes()['data'];
------^
```

I have no problem in localhost, but in other host, when i check the code, i see this error :

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in** ....

I have shown where the code causes error .

i have also used :

```
$data[] = (string) $value->attributes()['data'];
```

(without `0` in `[]`)

How can i solve it ?

Comment: The issue is not with the first square brackets, it's with the ones after `attributes()`.

Comment: It's got nout to do with that first `[`, it's your function array dereferencing (the last `[]`). You need PHP >= 5.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Array Referencing was first added in PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102).

The code from PHP.net:

```
<?php
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
?>
```

So you'd have to change

```
$data[] = (string)$value->attributes()['data'];
```

to

```
$attributes = $value->attributes();
$data[] = (string)$attributes['data'];
```

If your PHP version is older than 5.4.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line:

```
$value->attributes()['data'];
```

Which is because you're using a version of PHP which doesn't support function array dereferencing, which was only added in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

To get around it, you'd have to call the method first, and then access its properties, eg:

```
$someVariable = $value->attributes();
$data[] = (string) $someVariable['data'];
```